# Flutter project issue

Tags: flutter

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Asus\Flutter Apps\vision_tflite\android/gradlew.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have downgraded "Language support for java(TM) by Redhat". But it doesn't solve.